# I want to create a custom post type single template but I didn't show a single template option in the theme builder

Tags: wordpress, elementor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eWxH.jpg)

I want to create a custom post type single template but I didn't show a single template option in the theme builder

Answer (score 0):

It says 'Single Post'. That's what you need.